# Holomorphic series with its real part positive $f(z)=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n z^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Let $$f(z)=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n z^n,$$

$f \in H(B(0,1))$, and $\operatorname{Re} f(z)\ge 0$, 
$\forall z \in B(0,1) $.

Prove:

(1) $| a_n | \le2$;

(2) $|a_1^2-a_2| \le 2, |2a_1a_2-a_1^3-a_3|\le2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas:

a) Introduce $g(z)=(1-f(z))/(1+f(z))$. Show  that $|g|<1$ in the unit disk.

b) Do some algebra of power series (much like the long division of polynomials) to get 
$$g(z)=-\frac{1}{2}a_1z +\frac14(a_1^2-2a_2)z^2-\frac18(a_1^3-4a_1a_2+4a_3)z^3+\dots \tag1$$

c) Conclude that $|a_1|\le 2$ from the Schwarz lemma.

d) Apply (c) to the function $f_n(z)=n^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(\zeta^k z)$ where $\zeta=\exp(2\pi i /n)$.

The form of expansion (1) suggests it may be relevant for part (2), but you'll have to think more there.

Answer (score 1):

Part (1) follows from the [Herglotz representation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_harmonic_function#Herglotz_representation_theorem_for_holomorphic_functions).

For part (2):

$$ \frac{1}{f(z)} = 1 - a_1 z + (a_1^2-a_2) z^2 - (a_1^3 - 2 a_1a_2 + a_3) z^3 +  \dotsc
$$